# Undefined symbols _EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id

Tags: c++, macos, openssl, clang

I have this C++ code which does not compile on OS X:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <openssl/evp.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
        EVP_PKEY_CTX *pctx;
        pctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_EC, NULL);
        return 0;
}
```

At link I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id", referenced from:
      _main in test-a22ea1.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

compiled with:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test -lssl -lcrypto
```

OpenSSl doc, says that it should be defined:
https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/EVP_PKEY_CTX_new.html

This code works perfectly on a Linux (Debian 7 with OpenSSL 1.0.1e). But not on OS X. Any suggestion?

My config:

- OS X: 10.11.2
- clang: Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
- openSSL: OpenSSL 1.0.2e 3 Dec 2015 (installed with Homebrew)

Thank and happy new year :)

Comment: C is not C++ is not C!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiling and linking OpenSSL on Ubuntu vs OSX](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14150772).

Comment: If you want to see examples of actually using some C++ features with OpenSSL, then take a look at [How to generate RSA private key using openssl](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30493975/608639) and [Using openssl to generate a DSA key pair](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22580463/608639). The answers use `unique_ptr` to automatically free resources acquired with OpenSSL's `*_new` functions, like `RSA_new` and `DSA_new`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the linker perhaps picking up another version of `ssl` and `crypto` library files that were already installed on the system? Try adding the -L switch with the path to the homebrew-installed files.